# CSS3 Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries

What is the difference between these two instructions?

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

and

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older
>   user agents. User agents must process media queries starting with
>   ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

In real use scenarios, the `only screen` query is used to target specific mobile browsers that support modern CSS.

From http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet

Even more clearly

> Prefixing a media queries with the "only" keyword will cause non
>   CSS3-compliant browsers to ignore the rule.

From http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying.html